# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object error, but SQL works

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL query that run successfully in phpmyadmin, but in PHP it invoke `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` error message. Can you give any ideas what can be wrong?

```
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_server,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_database);
    if (!$con)
        {
          $error_auth="Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          return false;
        };

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `start`, `timetable`.`id`, `guide_id`, `name`  FROM `timetable` INNER JOIN `excursions` ON `timetable`.`excursion_id` = `excursions`.`id` WHERE `name` LIKE ?  LIMIT 150");
    if (!$stmt)
    {
         echo "Errormessage: %s\n";
         echo $mysqli->error;
    }
    //, $from_date,  $to_date
    $stmt->bind_param("s",  "%".$str_search."%");
```

**And error:**

```
Errormessage: %s
<!--error--><br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in <b>\json\classes\tigran_search_transaction_script.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
```

Comment: Change `echo $mysqli->error;` to `echo $con->error;`.  You don't have a `$mysqli` variable, you have `$con`.

Comment: I got. `No database selected`. Now I know the problem!

Comment: Well, there ya go! :-D

Comment: But, It's wierd that it was not selected at connection.

Comment: You'll still run into problems as you cannot bind parameters to the return value of `prepare()` (that returns a boolean). Check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Comment: @jeroen: That's not correct.  You are looking at the *wrong* `prepare()` method.  You want http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.  Which returns a `mysqli_stmt` when it succeeds (and `FALSE` when it doesn't).

Comment: @RocketHazmat I think I'll just stick to PDO :(

Comment: @jeroen: The method you linked is when you create a new `mysqli_stmt` via `$mysqli->stmt_init()`.  Why you'd want to do it that way, I don't know :-)  I agree MySQLi can be a bit confusing :-D

Comment: Well, the problem was in wrongly included file, so database setting up parameters were empty. I changed required_once("mysql.config.php") to require and everything lanched. @Rocket Hazmat, your comment was most useful, write this as answer and I will select it :) 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is your 'bind_param' statement:

'bind_param' expect a **variable** that it can take the 'reference' of. You pass a 'calculated' **value**. Sadly, only PHP knows where that is stored and it will not tell anyone about where it lives.

what you need to do is:

```
$my_str_search = "%".$str_search."%";

$stmt->bind_param("s",  $my_str_search);
```

All will be well as PHP can now tell the database exactly where to look get all the information, in the correct format, that it needs.

Comment: I think the real problem is when `if (!$stmt)` is true and OP prints error, he does not exit the script, thus trying to call `bind_param` on `$stmt` will fail

Comment: This was also an issue. But it was not the problem, actually.